# How to p4 obliterate stream

Tags: perforce

I'm a new user trying out P4V, and created a few test streams and workspaces.

I'm able to delete streams from streams view but the file still exists on the tree view (and in my disk) and I wanted to obliterate the streams entirely.

However `p4 obliterate //depot/*` returns No records to delete.

What should my paths be?

`p4 dirs -D //depot/` also returned `//depot/ - no such file(s).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `admin` or `super` permission to be able to obliterate.

To obliterate everything in the `depot` depot do:

```
p4 obliterate -y //depot/...
```

To clean everything out of your workspace that isn't in the depot (i.e. everything, if you've just obliterated the whole depot), do:

```
p4 clean
```

Comment: Thank you! This prompted me to take another look at the P4Admin GUI and there's an Administration > Obliterate function that did the job.